# Why are Force users limited in their telekinetic attacks?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

If I can apply enough force to my enemy's neck to choke off his air supply, that same amount of force can be applied to their carotid arteries and render them unconscious instantly. A vastly lesser force could explode a blood vessel in their brain. Why is telekinesis not an instagib weapon in Star Wars?

Comment: In Universe: Jedi don't want to kill, Sith want to cause pain. Out of Universe? It just wouldn't be fun to watch

Comment: Because then it'd have to be called *Inception* and there'd be no +40yo IP to suckle from. Also, *Scanners* is R rated, so it's hard to sell toys.

Answer (score 6):

Using the force still requires effort - look at the strain on Luke's face during his Dagobah training or even Yoda throwing off the objects Dooku throws at him.

The effort and focus required to pinch an artery would cost the force user to the extent that they'd be open to attack. It might be even be "impossible" to perform such fine control - certainly for many Jedi or Sith but the strongest.

Choking simply requires less fine control - crushing neck vertebrae even less so.

Comment: Not that hard if you're a blood bender.